# Directional indicators in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I would be grateful if someone could advise, please.

I have a simple table set up in SSRS 2008 R2. It gives me the number of processes completed, per month, so:

Jan   200
Feb   150
March 250

I have managed to set a simple indicator by each, which shows red if the value is <200 and green if the value is >200.

I would however like to put a directional indicator in that will give an up-arrow if the value is higher than the previous month's. So in the example above, next to Feb we would see a down arrow. Next to March we would see an up arrow.

I have added an indicator to the table, then selected directional In indicator values, then values and states, I have deleted all but one of the arrow icons and tried to write an expression to get it to do what I want. But I have not succeeded.

If you know of a way round this seemingly simple, yet puzzling, problem - please can you let me know?

I hope I have explained it clearly. Please bear with me, as this is the first time I have posted on this site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Previous Function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156372%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) that returns the value or the specified aggregate value for the previous instance of an item within the specified scope.

For example:

```
=IIf(Fields!ProcessesCompleted.Value < Previous(Fields!ProcessesCompleted.Value), <display DOWN icon>, <display UP icon>)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion above. I tried to add this (by adding a column to my report, then inserting the above statement (using my fields), but got this error message:   "Failed to preview report. The Value expression for the textbox 'Textbox 4' has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset."                           Any suggestions to make this work would be really appreciated. Many thanks again.

Comment: this is strictly connected to the report structure and datasets used. Take a look here to more info about Scope parameter: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156372%28v=sql.100%29.aspx